# Black Screen Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols= 1
        self.inside= GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols= 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Pan Card No: '))
        self.pan= TextInput(multiline= FALSE)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.pan)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Aadhar Card No: '))
        self.aadhar= TextInput(multiline= FALSE)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.aadhar)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text='Phone No: '))
        self.phoneno= TextInput(multiline= FALSE)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.phoneno)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit= Button(text='Submit', font_size=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)
    def pressed(self, instance):
        pan=self.pan.text
        aadhar=self.aadhar.text
        phoneno=self.phoneno.text


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
if __name__== "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

For my above code, I'm getting a black screen on running Kivy. It was working alright a few minutes ago and started showing the black screen all of a sudden after I added the pressed function.
Using Kivy[base] on Python 3.8.2 using VSCode. Please tell me why its occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling error. change:

```
def __int__(self, **kwargs):
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```